# chained select dropdown with php mysql and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have some difficulty with my 'select', this is my case:

Database : **dbProduct**

```
tb_item
---------------------
id_item | name_item |
---------------------
110     | item 1    |
111     | item 2    |
---------------------
```

```
tb_content
--------------------------
id_content | name_content|
--------------------------
110-001    | content A   |
110-002    | content B   |
111-001    | content C   |
111-002    | content D   |
--------------------------
```

How to make output select box:

```
Choose Item: ---------------
             |id_item  | V |
             ---------------
             |110          |
             ---------------
             |111          |  
             ---------------
```

If I choose `id_item = 110`, the select box should output:

```
-----------------                   
Content Name| V |                     
-----------------                     
   content A    |                    
   content B    |                    
-----------------
```

If choose id_item = 111, the select box should output:

```
-----------------
Content Name| V |
-----------------
   content C    |
   content D    |
-----------------
```

How do I implement this? And Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are your problems implementing it? What have you tried? Can you provide some code with what you came up so far?

Comment: My first suggestion would be splitting `id_content` in `tb_content` into 2 columns, with a foreign key on  `tb_content.id_item` and `tb_item.id_item`